# Swift: NFCError Code=202 "Session is invalidated unexpectedly"

Tags: ios, swift, nfc

I'm trying to use NFC. I followed those steps:

- Enabled NFC in the AppID configuration
  [image: App ID Config]
- Created a provisioning profile and installed it
  [image: Provisioning]
- Added NFC capability to the target
  [image: NFC target]
  [image: NFC target code]
- Added the privacy description in the plist file
  [image: Plist]

After this I imported CoreNFC and implemented those code:

```
@available(iOS 11.0, *)    
    extension EventPreviewViewController: NFCNDEFReaderSessionDelegate {
            func readerSession(_ session: NFCNDEFReaderSession, didInvalidateWithError error: Error) {
                let alert = UIAlertController.withOkButton(andTitle: NSLocalizedString("TitleWarning"), andText: NSLocalizedString("ErrorNFCInvalidate"), okHandler: nil)
                self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
            }

            func readerSession(_ session: NFCNDEFReaderSession, didDetectNDEFs messages: [NFCNDEFMessage]) {
                // TODO
            }
        }


class EventPreviewViewController: UITableViewController {
@available(iOS 11.0, *)
var nfcSession: NFCNDEFReaderSession {
        return NFCNDEFReaderSession(delegate: self, queue: nil, invalidateAfterFirstRead: true)
    }

    @IBAction func startAccess(_ sender: UIButton) {
    if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
                    nfcSession.begin()
                } else {
                    let alert = UIAlertController.withOkButton(andTitle: NSLocalizedString("TitleWarning"), andText: NSLocalizedString("ErrorNFCUnsupported"), okHandler: nil)
                    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
    }
}
```

Why I keep getting "Error Domain=NFCError Code=202 "Session is invalidated unexpectedly" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Session is invalidated unexpectedly}"?

Comment: Have you taken the declaration of `nfcSession` out of context?  I presume so, because the code as shown won't compile.  You need `nfcSession` to be a property, not a local constant or it will be released as soon as its enclosing function returns.

Comment: I tried making `nfcSession` a property (see my comment in the answer below) but still not working...

Comment: Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56681258/edit) your question to show the relevant property declaration in context - what object did you make it a property of?  What is the lifetime of that object?  The message says that your reader session is being released.

Answer (score 3):

update for ios13 / swift 5.1

a) original sample from Apple does sometimes fails the same error.

(https://developer.apple.com/documentation/corenfc/building_an_nfc_tag-reader_app)

b) if fails (seems a be stupid.. anyway.. works..) **reboot** device. It happens ;(

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure but below line causing this error `Session is invalidated unexpectedly`

When I was worked with `CoreNFC`, I was faced similar kind of issue. Fix it by defining as `property`

```
let nfcSession = NFCNDEFReaderSession(delegate: self, queue: DispatchQueue(label: "queueName", attributes: .concurrent), invalidateAfterFirstRead: true)
```

I suggest you need to define `nfcSession` as property.

```
var nfcSession: NFCNDEFReaderSession?

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    self.nfcSession = NFCNDEFReaderSession(delegate: self, queue: DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background), invalidateAfterFirstRead: false)
    self.nfcSession?.begin()
    return true
}
```

## Update:

You can define a property for iOS 11 like below.

```
@available(iOS 10.0, *)
    var session: NFCNDEFReaderSession?
```

Comment: How can I make that property available only on iOS11 or newer?

`@available(iOS 11.0, *)
    var nfcSession: NFCNDEFReaderSession {
        return NFCNDEFReaderSession(delegate: self, queue: nil, invalidateAfterFirstRead: true)
    }`

It's not working, I get the same error.

Comment: UPDATE: Stored properties cannot be marked potentially unavailable with '@available'